# How to make a non web thread run with the Spring Security Anonymous Use?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 3.1 and I have some code which I execute on web application strartup from  the init method of a Servlet. Problems is that there is no valid Authentication object at the time my servlet init method execute. My servlet is configured to run after the Spring has been initialized and spring security is full configured.

How do I make the code in my init method run as the anonymous user in spring security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new AnonymousAuthenticationToken(key, login, authorities))
```

where any non-empty string should do as a key, login like "anonymous", authorities - whichever you want him to have, at least one.